# Printer color calibration software for "manual" calibration

Tags: software, printing, color-management, software-recommendation

I don't think that I need professional calibration for my printer (its for private use, and an MX925 only anyways) but I thought that since I have a color checker passport, there might be some way to create a profile that isn't really good, but better than nothing.

The idea is that for each swatch I would print out multiple ones that are similar and chose the one that looks most similar to that of my color checker passport (probably best in sunlight or so). From that a software should theoretically be able to create a profile that is a bit better that none at all.

Does there exist such a software?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that any such software exists.  Even if it did, you would get marginal results or even get less accurate color than looking for publicly available ICC profiles that are published for the printer and your given paper type (if you are using a typical paper with the printer).  Even if you are not, you can print out sheets and send them in to various places to have them build a profile for you pretty cheaply.

Comment: I would prefer those profiles, if they were available for 3rd party inks, which they don't seem to be. The goal was to spend no money at all and work with what I have (a bit for the fun of it of course too). Using such a service starts here at around 30USD per sheet, and given that I would probably want multiple ones this is about the same cost as a used colorimeter.

Comment: I've found that if a printer comes with profiles when installed you can get very good results with the OEM ink. However, I've also tried some 3rd party inks with really large color shifts. Correctable with a custom profile but no way using a colorchecker would work. All profling software requires much more than 24 patches to create printer profiles.

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative to an own printer profile created with a spectrophotometer is working with the ICC profiles that some paper manufacturers offer as standard on their homepage for download... I only calibrate my screens with a Spyder4Elite and print with these type of ICC profiles to print.

Comment: See my comment on AJ Hendersons answer

Comment: Yes indeed, it's difficult for 3rd party inks. Therefore, or you save money with the inks and need your own profiles from a spectrophotometer (not colorimeter, which can only measure light from a display), or you save in spectro, but pay more money for the original money with more constant colors.